# Using Jquery with facebook JS SDk

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using jquery to achieve a variety of stuff in my pages, which includes showing and hiding div elements.

Now I also have the facebook JS SDK in the master page to check whether the user has signed out of facebook and making graph api calls.

The problem is sometimes, it takes a while for response from facebook to come and in this while, div elements which are hidden by jquery on $.ready, can be seen by the user.

Any ideas how to better this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. So I was finally able to resolve the issue. You should load the FB Javascript SDK asynchronously as shown below

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

For more details, please refer http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

A thing which I noticed, all your methods containing FB object such as FB.api etc. should be within the same closure as FB.init or the FB object is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cleaner method, try this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({xfbml: true});
};

$(function() {
  $.getScript({url: document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'});
}
```

Insert this code either inline or in a separate Javascript file.

Notes:

- This example does not define **appID**, **cookie** or **status**.  You could add them to fbAsyncInit.
- Tested with JQuery 1.8.2.
- I found the **#fb-root** div to be unnecessary.

Comment: #fb-root is purported to be used in certain cross-domain situations with certain browsers, same as the channel file.

Answer (score 0):

i think the graph api calls have a callback function for when they complete. invoke your jquery code from there instead of $.ready

Comment: well the thing is I want to invoke my jquery code before graph api calls. The issue is graph api calls result in a delay and I want my code executed as soon as page loads.

Comment: I see. my bad! 
1. How about you start the offending divs hidden?
or
2. How about you make the graph calls after loading the page? So you do what you do with jquery and then start invoking the graph stuff.

Without some code samples or a webpage it's really hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

[Defer to window.load](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#defer-to-window-load)

Comment: no, defering is not what is needed. If you read carefully I want to make this happen earlier, basically before FB JS Sdk starts making api calls. If I delay then user will see elements which are presently hidden by using hide() methods within $.ready(). I hope I was clearer this time.